# How can I get the maximum values of a tensor along a dimension?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, libtorch

I have a 3D tensor and would like to take the max values along the 0th dimension in Libtorch.

I know how to do this in Python (PyTorch) but I'm having trouble doing this in LibTorch.

In LibTorch my code is

```
auto target_q_T = torch::rand({5, 10, 1});
auto max_q = torch::max({target_q_T}, 0);
std::cout << max_q;
```

It returns this long, repeating error.

```
note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*)’
  611 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/ostream:611:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/iii/tor/m_gym/multiv_normal.cpp:432:18: note:   cannot convert ‘max_q’ (type ‘std::tuple<at::Tensor, at::Tensor>’) to type ‘const char*’
  432 |     std::cout << max_q;
      |                  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/istream:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/sstream:38,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/c10/macros/Macros.h:246,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/c10/core/DeviceType.h:8,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/c10/core/Device.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:11,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/ATen/core/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/function_hook.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/cpp_hook.h:2,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/variable.h:6,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/autograd/autograd.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/autograd.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:7,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/torch.h:3,
                 from /home/iii/tor/m_gym/multiv_normal.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/ostream:624:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Traits> std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*)’
  624 |     operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const signed char* __s)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

This is how it works in Python.

```
target_q_np = torch.rand(5, 10, 1)
max_q = torch.max(target_q_np, 0)
max_q

torch.return_types.max(
values=tensor([[0.8517],
        [0.7526],
        [0.6546],
        [0.9913],
        [0.8521],
        [0.9757],
        [0.9080],
        [0.9376],
        [0.9901],
        [0.7445]]),
indices=tensor([[4],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [1],
        [0],
        [2],
        [4],
        [4],
        [4]]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the compiler error, it basically tells you that you are trying to print a tuple of two tensors. That's because the C++ code works exactly like the python code and returns the max values and their respective indices (your python code prints exactly that).
You need [std get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) to extract the tensors from the tuple :

```
auto target_q_T = torch::rand({5, 10, 1});
auto max_q = torch::max({target_q_T}, 0);
std::cout << "max: " << std::get<0>(max_q) 
          << "indices: " << std::get<1>(max_q)
          << std::endl;
```

In C++17 you should also be able to write

```
auto [max_t, idx_t] = torch::max({target_q_T}, 0);
std::cout << ... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I never found the equivent use of `max` in LibTorch like there is in PyTorch so I did a workaround.
The `max` in LibTorch will take the max from a 1D array so I loop over the indexed array and concatenate the results. Which, in effect returns the same thing as torch.max(target_q_np, 0).

My solution in LibTorch (C++). The array of max values is returned in reverse order as the original tensor, so I flip it.

```
auto target_q_T = torch::rand({5, 10, 1});

torch::Tensor zero_max;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    zero_max = torch::cat({torch::max({target_q_T[i]}).unsqueeze(-1), zero_max}, 0);
}
zero_max = zero_max.flip(-1);
```